# Is there a way to get thin scrollbars in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, overlay-scrollbars

I like the new overlay/thin scrollbars from Natty but I don't like Unity and the Speed, so I will stay on Ubuntu 10.10 for a while. Is there a way to get the new scrollbars in Ubuntu 10.10 (PPA/DEB-package/GNOME-Conf or whatever)?

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not available in 10.10.

**The offical packages in [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ayatana-scrollbar) are just for Natty and Oneiric:**

> Packages in Distributions
>
> “overlay-scrollbar” source package in Oneiric
>
> Version 0.1.12-0ubuntu1 uploaded on 2011-04-27
>
> “overlay-scrollbar” source package in Natty
>
> Version 0.1.12-0ubuntu1 uploaded on 2011-04-27

Alternatively in Natty; you can switch to `the Classic Ubuntu desktop` and it has the new overlay-scrollbars:

[image]

Comment: Sry, I only have 10.10, so I don't have Unity :/

Comment: @Bluefirex Don't worry,the point is you can't have scroll-bars in 10.10 in the meantime. But I recommend you to give Unity a try if you want to try new awesome things;like the scroll-bars;).any other help I am ready .And please consider accepting an answer.